# How to detect the language used in a column and put it in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, language-detection

I have the following `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': ['Id159', 'Id758', 'Id146', 'Id477', 'Id212', 'Id999'],
    'comment' : ["I inboxed you", '123', 123, 'je suis fatigué', "j'aime", 'ما نوع الجهاز بالضبط']  
})
```

It has the following display:

```
    user    comment
0   Id159   I inboxed you
1   Id758   123
2   Id146   123
3   Id477   je suis fatigué
4   Id212   j'aime
5   Id999   ما نوع الجهاز بالضبط
```

My **goal** is to get a new column containing language used in the column `df['comment']` as follows:

```
    user    comment         language
0   Id159   I inboxed you   en
1   Id758   123             UNKNOWN
2   Id146   123             UNKNOWN
3   Id477   je suis fatigué fr
4   Id212   j'aime          fr
5   Id999   ما نوع الجهاز بالضبط  ar
```

**My code**

```py
from langdetect import detect

df['language'] = [detect(x) for x in df['comment']]
```

When I tried to use `detect` I faced the following message error:

```
LangDetectException: No features in text.
```

I tried to add an `if else` statement but douldn't solve the issue.

Any help from your side will be highly appreciated (I **upvote** all answers)

Than you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you clarify all exception cases you want to set as `UNKNOWN`.

Anyway, I assume you want to set non-string and numeric into `UNKNOWN`.

Then,

```py
df["language"] = [
    detect(x) if isinstance(x, str) and not x.isnumeric() else "UNKNOWN"
    for x in df["comment"]
]
```

EDIT:

Or for more general approach (though not really recommended) you can just use exception handling

```py
def f(x):
    try:
        return detect(x)
    except:
        return "UNKNOWN"

df["language"] = [f(x) for x in df["comment"]]
```

Comment: Thanks!  @NoThIng , I applied your second code in your answer to my actual `dataframe` and it worked as expected!

Answer (score 2):

Haven't you try it to add an if statement to check the length of the input text before calling the detect() function. If the length of the input text is less than 3 characters, you can assign the value "UNKNOWN" to the language column for that row ?

I would comment on this, but I am not allowed to comment yet.

Comment: Thanks @Andy25 for the answer, what you stated make sens to solve the problem as I described it, however I want a solution for my actual `dataframe` with more than 3000 rows and more complex `comment` column

Comment: df['language'] = ['UNKNOWN' if len(x) < 3 else detect(x) for x in df['comment']] => This should fix the LangDetectException: No features in text. error and correctly assign the language of each comment to the language column in the df DataFrame...i think someone else already post it something similar

Answer (score 2):

`langdetect` throws an error if it doesn't see any letters in its input.

Use custom function to catch that specific error:

```
from langdetect import detect, lang_detect_exception

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': ['Id159', 'Id758', 'Id146', 'Id477', 'Id212', 'Id999'],
    'comment' : ["I inboxed you", '123', 123, 'je suis fatigué', "j'aime", 'ما نوع الجهاز بالضبط']
})

def check_lang(val):
    try:
        lang = detect(str(val))
    except lang_detect_exception.LangDetectException:
        lang = 'UNKNOWN'
    return lang

df['language'] = df['comment'].apply(lambda x: check_lang(x))
print(df)
```

The output:

```
    user               comment language
0  Id159         I inboxed you       en
1  Id758                   123  UNKNOWN
2  Id146                   123  UNKNOWN
3  Id477       je suis fatigué       fr
4  Id212                j'aime       fi
5  Id999  ما نوع الجهاز بالضبط       ar
```